# Which version of Xcode suitable for macOs 10.13?

Tags: macos, xcode

I need to download Xcode in my Mac OS 10.13. Which Xcode version suitable for it? It is not 10.13.6 just 10.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xcode 10.X** is only for **Mac OS 10.13.6 or later**. You should install **[Xcode 9.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-version-without-premium-developer-account)**.

> [**Xcode 10** is available in the Mac App Store and includes SDKs for iOS 12, watchOS 5, macOS 10.14, and tvOS 12. Xcode 10 supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 10 requires a Mac running **macOS 10.13.6 or later**.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes)

References:

- [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-version-without-premium-developer-account